# php iconv function not working on linux hosting

Tags: php, linux, unicode, utf-8, iconv

Please have a look on following code:

```
<?php
    function unicode_decode($str){

            return preg_replace("/\\\u([0-9A-F]{4})/ie", "iconv('utf-16', 'utf-8',hex2str(\"$1\"))", $str);    

    }

function hex2str($hex) {

    $r = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hex) - 1; $i += 2)

    $r .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i] . $hex[$i + 1]));

    return $r;

}
$var="\u092e\u0941\u0930\u0932\u0940 \u0938\u093e\u0930";
$var =  unicode_decode($var);
echo $var;
?>
```

This code works perfectly in windows hosting and output is "मुरली सार". However, in linux hosting its output is random, showing like chinese characters"⸉䄉〉㈉䀉 㠉㸉". It seems like linux hosting doesn't work with inconv function of php.

How to solve this problem in linux hosting?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to try `mb_convert_encoding` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: I believe `echo json_decode("\"$var\"");` will do instead of all that code.

Comment: [You're welcome](http://3v4l.org/lskhR)

Comment: thanks it works with json_decode() but i need it working on return preg_replace("/\\\u([0-9A-F]{4})/ie", "iconv('utf-16', 'utf-8',hex2str(\"$1\"))", $str); line because it filters the unwanted english, brackets and commas characters

Comment: @all I have string which looks like follows:[[["\u0905\u092A\u092E\u093E\u0928\u093F\u0924 \u0915\u0930\u0928\u093E","abase","Apam\u0101nita karan\u0101",""]],[["verb",["\u0905\u092A\u092E\u093E\u0928\u093F\u0924 \u0915\u0930\u0928\u093E"],[["\u0905\u092A\u092E\u093E\u0928\u093F\u0924 \u0915\u0930\u0928\u093E",["depreciate","abase","mortify","demean","insult","lay low"],,0.260865599]],"abase",2],["",...
so i need to make it work with iconv.

Comment: So what you have *is* JSON! Then decode the JSON with `json_decode` and then filter whatever needs filtering on regular characters!

Comment: ya JSON is the best alternative :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-16 has two variations: big-endian and little-endian. They differ in the order of the bytes in the code units: the character U+1234 would be encoded as `'\x12\x34'` in big-endian, but as `'\x34\x12'` in little endian.

It looks like iconv is assuming different versions on different systems. You make it use the big-endian version on all systems by using `utf-16be`:

```
return preg_replace("/\\\u([0-9A-F]{4})/ie", "iconv('utf-16be', 'utf-8',hex2str(\"$1\"))", $str);
```